# How to highlight PARTIAL matching duplicates across 1 column in Google Sheets using conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

As the title says, I'm trying to highlight partial duplicates for 1 column in Google Sheets using conditional formatting.

Here's what I have so far:
`=if(C1<>"",Countif(C$1:C,left(C1,5)& "*") > 1)`

This works, but the issue is the "left" makes it so the code only highlight cells that are duplicates from the start.

So for instance, the formula won't highlight "1exampletest" and "2exampletest" because the first 5 characters are not the same...which is something I want the formula to be able to highlight.

Does anyone know the right formula for detecting partial duplicates regardless of when the duplicate is occurring?

Comment: sheet is sort of a mess, i'm trying to find partial duplicates no matter where the duplicates are...so I want the formula to be able to detect that this is a duplicate: "halfexample" "wholeexample".....currnetly the formula I've shown will not detect it as a duplicate...however it will detect "examplehalf" "examplewhole" as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways how to do it which may or may not work for you (because you did not provide a geniue sample)

[image: 0]

### _______________________________________________________________

or with `REGEXMATCH` like: **`=REGEXMATCH(A1, "example")`**

[image: 0]

### _______________________________________________________________

```
=OR(IF(C1<>"",COUNTIF(C$1:C,LEFT(C1,5)&"*")>1),IF(C1<>"",COUNTIF(C$1:C,"*"&RIGHT(C1,5))>1))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. For my situation though, it needs to be able to identify any sort of duplicate - not just one particular word or phrase

I didnt realize there might be confusion, so here would be a list I want to get right:

www.google.com
google.com
google.com/help
google.com/examplehelp
sites.google.com
youtube.com
forum.youtube.com
www.youtube
youtube.com

I want to be able to identify all the google sites as duplicates and all the youtube sites as duplicates....and this list goes on and on with hundreds of different sites and versions of the site

Comment: That works for right and left, but what if u want to find a duplicate in the middle?

Comment: @crammerstyle you can use multiple `MID` for that and include it in `OR`

Comment: if you mean from changing LEFT to MID, it doesnt seem to work

Comment: still need help